# Keystone.js nested categories

Tags: keystonejs

I am trying to implement nested categories for Post model.

What I have:

```
Post.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    state: { type: Types.Select, options: 'draft, published, archived', default: 'draft', index: true },
    author: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'User', index: true },
    publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, index: true, dependsOn: { state: 'published' } },
    content: {
        extended: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 300 },
    },
    categories: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'PostCategory', index: true }
});
```

And category

```
PostCategory.add({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    subCategories: { type: Types.TextArray }
});
```

Now I can add a list of subcategories to each category. 
What I can't do is to display subcategories while creating a post. Also if I change category I need to load sub categories related to selected category.

My plan was to achieve that with watch functionality but it seems only works on save.

Another thing I was thinking about was to add subcategories as relationship, see ref:

```
categories: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'PostCategory.subCategories', index: true }
```

But it isn't working as well.

So, if anybody has any ideas how to achieve that, please share.
Thanks.

P.S. Don't hesitate to ask any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I created nested categories by creating a new model 'PostSubCategory' that allows the user to assign the parent category to the child category when they create the child category:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
* PostSubCategory Model
* ==================
*/

var PostSubCategory = new keystone.List('PostSubCategory', {
    autokey: { from: 'name', path: 'key', unique: true },
});

PostSubCategory.add({
    name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  parentCategory: {
    type: Types.Relationship,
    ref: 'PostCategory',
    required: true,
    initial: true
  }
});


PostSubCategory.relationship({ ref: 'Post', path: 'subcategories' });

PostSubCategory.register();
```

Then in my Post.js, I add a field to choose a subcategory with a filter on that field to only select from subcategories that are children of the parent category selected:

```
subcategory: {
    type: Types.Relationship,
    ref: 'PostSubCategory',
    many: false,
    filters: { parentCategory: ':categories' }
}
```

I'm not sure how well this would work for deeper nesting, and I do have an issue in the edit Post admin ui where changing the parent category for a post doesn't update the available subcategories to choose from until you save and refresh. But it got me far enough along for getting parent/child categories to work.